# C# why code compiles without any name spaces included

Tags: c#

I tried the following

```
// no using statements here, not even using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr = new string[3] { "A" , "B", "C" };
    }             
}
```

My question is simple, even without any using statements, how come compiler is able to compile this, more specifically, shouldn't there be a compile time error because I am trying to build an array and System.Array is not accessible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `String` instead of `string` you will get the error you expect.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: He'll get an error, but I don't think it's the one that he expects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Arrays are part of the language. You don't need to reference a namespace to use them.

Answer (score 32):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about what `using` means. A `using` directive is for *determining what a simple name means in your program at compile time*. When you say `using Foo;` that means "if *the text* of this program uses the simple name `Bar`, and it doesn't seem like anything named `Bar` is in scope where the name is used then try checking to see if there is a type called `Bar` inside namespace `Foo`".

Your program does not contain any simple names! (`string` is not a simple name; it is a keyword of the language.) Therefore there is no need to have any `using` directive to resolve the non-existing simple names.

`using` does not at all mean "this program uses features that require types found in this assembly", which is what you seem to think it means.  `using` directives are only about (1) simple name resolution, and (2) extension method name resolution.

Answer (score 6):

`string[]` will translate to `System.Array` while compiling. Since its already fully qualified, it doesn't need any `using` statements.

Answer (score 5):

You're not referring by name to any namespaced type but yours (the `Program` class).

`string` and `[]` are aliases that are indeed equivalent to `System.String` and `System.Array` respectively, but using them does not require pulling their counterparts' namespaces into scope.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't directly referencing the `Array` class or its members, so the compiler won't complain that you're trying to reference an unused namespace or type. You're just using notation that's part of the C# language itself to make arrays.

Comment: I don't think that is the question.

Comment: What about System.String, how is that accessible? I hover over the string[] part in the statement, and it shows "class System.String"

Comment: @Amit: `string` is a keyword, and like `[]` is part of the language, so same reason.

Comment: @Amit, it's a part of the language, it's a core feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using core things, you don't even need `System` for this to compile. The `System` namespace has extended functionality, some of the classes included in the System Namespace is:

- Action
- Func
- Console
- [And many more..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx)

As you are not trying to write something to the command prompt, creating actions or even asking for date using `DateTime`, you don't need to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

using statements do not include anything or provide any ekstra code. It only makes it simplier to code, because you don't have to write the whole path every time.

`string` automatically converts to System.String.

You can write this:

```
class Foo {
    string Bar() {
        return System.IO.File.Exists("path").ToString();
    }
}
```

or just

```
using System.IO;
class Foo {
    string Bar() {
        return File.Exists("path").ToString();
    }
}
```

both compiles to the same program.

Comment: He's asking why the code compiles without a using even though he's making an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are not necessary, you can organize with namespaces your code but you don't have to.
And common keywords are automatically referenced to the proper namespace.

For better understanding read this msdna document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx