# Namespaces vs physically coding?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Statements vs Namespace path? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628531/using-statements-vs-namespace-path-c)

I just want to know what the difference between including the namespace at the top of a C# class vs actually defining it in the program code.

So:

```
using System.Windows;
```

Or

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show();
```

Would having the namespace load the whole library or will only the needed data be used?

Sorry if it may seem confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between namespaces and assemblies. They're very different things.

`using` directives *only* talk about namespaces - and the two ways of referring to `MessageBox` will produce *exactly* the same code. Use whichever produces the most readable code - which is usually to use `using` directives and short names.

Answer (score 1):

The first is easier to read.  You should favour readability.  I don't think there is a compilation or loading benefit either way and if there is I haven't noticed it on 500kloc projects.

Answer (score 0):

Write the full namespace directly in your statements if some identifier is ambiguous.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

...

var msg = new Message(); // ambiguous
var msg1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Message(); // OK
var msg2 = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message(); // OK
```