# Usage of namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

What is the difference between defining a namespace by **using** keyword and simply giving the path to access the file wherever it is used ?? Does it cause any change in the internal working of the program, because the results seem to be the same

Comment: No difference. All it helps is for code readability and in some cases, avoids ambiguity with namespaces/types that happen to have similar paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6628574/2478357.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have any impact other than code readability and resolving type ambiguity.

Say you have 2 namespaces `SampleNamespace1` and `SampleNamespace2` that both have `MyClass` class. In order for you to specifically identify which `MyClass` to use is to correctly use the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you actually access the same namespace, there is no difference in the result. From the compiled code it's impossible to tell which way the namespace was specified.

Note that the namespace has nothing to do with the path of the file. They may be the same, but it's only the `namespace` statements that specify the namespace. To make it the same as the folder where the file lies, is only to make it easier to find the right file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result is the same, because there's no difference. 
Using is for clarify which class do You want to use, if there exists two class with the same name in more namespaces.

If You want to use both, with `using`, You can also create aliases for namespaces too to shorten Your code.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. except it make your code organizer because you don't write the full path every time.

one of it's advantages is when you have 2 or more classes with the same name but in different namespaces in that case you 'll need to write the full path for readability.